# Need input: Linear Regression prediction of difficulty of routes quite bad

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, linear-regression

(*Data*:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArLDiUd-U5dtg1H6y1_0f_m5f2by?e=OmKeWp)

I'm trying to predict the difficulty of a route. A route consists of a series of points, each 10 meters apart. Each point has the following information:

Path width
Forest density
Falling Velocity (What speed will your body reach in case of falling)
Slope

For each route there is also a given difficulty. **But** those difficulties were given by different persons and differ heavily. So one person gave a route a 4. But another one may have given this route a 2. So the data contains human errors.

**What i did so far:**
I calculated the mean and std for each **route**. So I took all points of one route and used it to calculate those statistic values. I also added the length of a route (number of points * 10).
(diff = difficulty of the route. Values from 1-12)

[image]

Then I took those values and put them into a Linear Regression Model. Which turned out to be a good start:

[image]

```
Mean Absolute Error: 1.239902061226418
Mean Squared Error: 2.3566221702532917
Root Mean Squared Error: 1.53512936596669
```

**Problem**

But now I don't know what to do to improve that, since I'm lacking the knowledge in machine learning.

I had the idea of using a neural network and just putting in all the points. The longest route is 5300 points long, so I would just say, 5300 inputs per route and fill points with 0 values for those routes, that are not long enough. 
Any info or input for something like that?

But I would also like to get a good result by using predictor values like shown above (mean, std and so on). So what can I do to improve the prediction?

Comment: Very generic advice: you might want to check if any of your input data falls outside of a normal curve, and maybe renormalize it, if necessary. Or maybe linear methods won't be enough, and you might need a more powerful predictor.

Comment: You mean reassess the difficulty? Would be quite difficult, to impossible, since I don't have any expertise in judging the difficulty of a route :/   What methods would you advice apart from linear then?   And how would I get more powerful predictors?

Comment: Not specifically the difficulty... I mean, checking how each of the input columns, not just the difficulty, behave; in order to make them work well on a linear algorithm, you will want to transform them so the're as linear or as possible, or at least follow a normal distribution.As for alternatives, see: https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-tour-of-machine-learning-algorithms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some of the steps you need to follow to develop a best model:

1. check for the outliers in the data and normilaze the data
2. Check the strength of the correlation between the independent and dependent
   variable.
3. Imputing the missing values or creating a separate segement
   to handle the missing values in the data columns.
4. Look for the variation inflation factor and tolerance
   This will imporve the data quality and imporve the accuracy of the model.